# Migrating GCM to FirebaseCM: onMessageReceived() not called in foreground

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, migrating

I'm trying to migrate Android client app from Google Cloud Messaging to Firebase Cloud Messaging. I strictly followed an [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm), but didn't succeed - `onMessageReceived()` method is not called when app in foreground.

So here are code snippets that I touched.

**build.gradle (project level)**

```
dependencies {
    //other stuff
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //this line in the bottom
```

and

```
dependencies {
    //other stuff here
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".service.FirebaseService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and

```
<service
  android:name=".service.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
  android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and

```
<service
     android:name=".service.RegistrationIntentService"
     android:exported="false" />
```

as childs of `<application>` tag.

**MyInstanceIDListenerService.java**

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

final String TAG = "Firebase instance id";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationIntentServiceEvent.TOKEN);
    intent.putExtra(RegistrationIntentServiceEvent.TOKEN, token);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

**FirebaseService.java**

```
public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


//OtherStuff

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
    String from = message.getFrom();
    Map data = message.getData();

    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + from); //Never appears in logcat
    //other stuff
}
}
```

**RegistrationIntentService**

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        synchronized (TAG) {
            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);//This works fine
            //and shows this line - 12-19 17:59:33.295 3146-5386/ru.bpc.mobilebank.bpc I/RegIntentService: GCM Registration Token: *some_token*

            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
    }
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationIntentServiceEvent.TOKEN);
    intent.putExtra(RegistrationIntentServiceEvent.TOKEN, token);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

Please, tell if i did something wrong and why registrations seems to be done properly, but the `onMessageReceived()` method is never called even if the app is in foreground. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** By the way, is adding SHA-1 keys in Firebase console necessary? maybe this could cause the problem? But Firebase says this action is optional.

Comment: Have you added google-services.json file in your app? Maybe you need to perform additional setup in Firebase console or configuration. Check here https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup if you have everything setup correctly

Comment: Ye, sure I added google-services.json. Ye, thanks for advice, I'll go and check setup, problem could be there.

Comment: By the way is adding SHA-1 keys in Firebase console necessary? maybe this could cause the problem? But Firebase says this is optional.

Comment: As in my case, I registered 2 SHA-1 fingerprints since I definitely use 2 different keystores, one for debug and one for production. I don't think that these steps are optional, in fact I think these are required, based on the documentation: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm. Can't find any "optional" words there, though, CMIIW.

Comment: Tanks for helping. Ye, maybe this could be the reason. There is no "optional" word in docs, but there is directly in Firebase console, when you add new projects (I have 6 product flavours, that made me add 6 projects, and each of them requires SHA-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using FCM then you should replace this

```
 <service android:name=".service.GcmService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

to

```
 <service android:name=".service.FirebaseService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

your service not registered properly..

Comment: As this guy have posted, @dmitry-smolyaninov class is now called FirebaseService, and not GcmService, the service isn't registered properly in AndroidManifest.xml. Upvoted.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just forgot to replace all original class names here. I renamed references and names of some classes in question to make in more clear and reasonable. In project classes still have GSM-names, but implement FCM functionality. I just don't make refactor untill solve this issue.