# GCM server and FCM client compatibility

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that receives push-notifications from a server. Both worked fine using Google Cloud Messaging, but now I'm migrate client to Firebase Cloud Messaging and meet some troubles.

I strictly [followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226897/migrating-gcm-to-firebasecm-onmessagereceived-not-called-in-foreground/41227237#41227237) the **[official guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)** to migrate my android-client. And the issue I've met is that my app properly receives push-notifications from Firebase console, but doesn't receive notifications from the server. Devices that run old clients on GCM still receive pushes.

This makes me think that server needs some updates, though guide says GCM-server and FCM-clients are compatible, and changing endpoints is optional.

So what could be the reason of this behavior? Is the problem really on the server, and if so, is the problem caused by deprecated endpoints or by something else?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: you need to change some setting from a server for FCM.

Comment: When notification send from server that time which code you use for GCM and FCM, can you please post it here

Comment: Ye, thats the problem. I'm begginer android-developer and I don't know, what's going on on server. The question purpose is to find out if the problem is on server-side or not. If so, I'll just ask server-devs to solve it.

Comment: And if you mean the code I use in client, then I [**posted**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226897/migrating-gcm-to-firebasecm-onmessagereceived-not-called-in-foreground/41227237#41227237) it in another question and included link to this question.

Comment: Ok Dmitry , so your side is not any issue, just for reference server guys : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39403196/1636758

Comment: Thank you very much for help, Mahesh!